# ENOENT on npm start error. Why am I getting this error and why is it looking for "My Pictures" directory?

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, material-ui, enoent

I am attempting to use MUI's Data Grid component in my React project. I have installed the package using $npm i @mui/x-data-grid. When I import DataGrid into my React component and run $npm start, I get the following ENOENT error. Anyone know why?

[image: Image of the import and error in console]

When the import is commented out, the error disappears:

[image]

Steps I've taken to resolve the issue:

1. Restart VS Code
2. Restart my computer
3. Run the "hotfix" from https://www.codejourney.net/2021/04/how-to-fix-npm-err-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rename/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an issue arising from incompatibility between @material-ui/core and @mui/x-data-grid.

There are a few possible solutions that I have found:

1. Use Webpack aliases to circumvent the problem via https://githubmemory.com/repo/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/2527
2. Install an older version of MUI Data Grid: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x
3. Go with a third party option for the data grid component. I have decided to proceed with the following: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Because it is renamed to `C:\Users\<user>\Pictures` since Windows 8?

BTW, why are you trying to access images outside your project directory? It works but it will be a nightmare to manage.

e.g. What are you going to do when you have to push the code to GitHub? Include `C:\Users\<user>\Pictures` to your source code?

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks for the reply. I'm not trying to access pictures outside my project directory. All my pics are stored in bkmkt-stats-web-main\src\pictures. No idea why it is referencing this folder since I installed x-data-grid inside the project directory and I am running the command in my project directory.

Comment: `@mui/x-data-grid` is not supposed to access the picture folder. Can you try to comment it and see whether the issue is still there. I tend to believe you mistakenly reference the folder somewhere else

Comment: Everything works fine when I comment out the DataGrid import.

Comment: I'm not sure then you can create an issue on their github page. One thing I do notice is you are using `@material-ui/core` and `@mui/x-data-grid` together, which are not supposed to be compatible with each other.

Comment: I think you may be on to something. After some googling, I believe this issue is indeed related to the incompatibility between @material-ui/core and @mui/x-data-grid. I'll let you know what I find.